# How to show all the records where the companyid = $companyid

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a page where I can show individual companies: http://kees.een-site-bouwen.nl/bedrijven/1

On the page it shows me the company with `id=1`. If I look at 'Tags' somewhere down the page, I can see 'Drukwerk'.

I used a joined table to show the tags for each company. There are more tags for that specific company, but it only shows me one tag "Drukwerk".

How can I show all the tags with the company id 1?

I'm still new to CodeIgniter so maybe it's really simple, but it's always worth asking here.

My model function to get the tags:

```
function bedrijven_tags($idbedrijven)
{
    $this->db->where('bedrijven.idbedrijven', $idbedrijven);
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('bedrijftags');
    $this->db->join('tags', 'bedrijftags.idtags = tags.idtags');
    $this->db->join('bedrijven', 'bedrijftags.idbedrijven = bedrijven.idbedrijven');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array();

    return $result;
}
```

My controller function to pass it to the views:

```
$data['query2'] = $this->bedrijven_model->bedrijven_tags($idbedrijven);
```

My views for showing the tags:

```
<?php foreach($query2 as $item2);?>
    <?= ($item2['Tag']); ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the views for showing the tags are wrong, just do this:

```
<?php 
     foreach($query2 as $item2){
       echo "<p>" . $item2['Tag'] . "</p>" ; 
     };
?>
```

Comment: there are a few typos in your code. but i got it working. thanks :) never knew it was that simple.